# Can std::vector<T> use T's move constructor, if exceptions are disabled?

Tags: c++

When `std::vector<T>` is out of storage at `emplace_back()`, it uses copy constructor to copy elements into the new storage, if `T`'s move constructor is not `noexcept`. This program prints `copy!` ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/E8xqWx)):

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

struct T {
    T() = default;
    T(T &&) { printf("move!\n"); }
    T(const T &) { printf("copy!\n"); }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<T> v;
    v.emplace_back();
    v.emplace_back();
}
```

If I mark move constructor with `noexcept`, this program prints `move!`. All this is expected.

Now, as I don't write code, which uses exceptions, I turn off exceptions with `-fno-exceptions`. And I expected, that my example (without `noexcept`) will print `move!`. But, both GCC and clang still print `copy!`.

Is this behavior mandated by the standard? Or is the compiler allowed to use `move`, it is just not optimized for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard does not say anything about what happens when you turn off exceptions. ISO C++ is a single language with no variants, by deactivating exceptions you switch to a dialect that is no longer covered by the standard.

An implementation could choose to enable what you ask for, but doing so would require additional effort by the library implementation. For a standard conformant implementation, the decision of whether to move or copy will be based on [`std::is_­nothrow_­move_­constructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_move_constructible), which is specified to only base that decision on the `noexcept` specifier in the move constructor's signature and not on whether or not the constructor actually throws an exception. To achieve what you desire, the implementation would have to implement a different detection mechanism for the `-fno-exceptions` dialect as a non-standard extension.

The relevant paragraph in the standard is [[vector.modifiers]](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.modifiers):

> `template<class... Args> constexpr reference emplace_back(Args&&... args);`
>
> [...]
>   If an exception is thrown while inserting a single element at the end
>   and `T` is *Cpp17CopyInsertable* or `is_­nothrow_­move_­constructible_­v<T>`
>   is `true`, there are no effects.

Even though it may not be obvious, this enforces calling the copy constructor when `is_­nothrow_­move_­constructible_­v` is false, as that is the only way for an implementation to comply with this requirement. Note that in earlier versions of the standard, things are even more subtle. The C++11 draft only says:

> If an exception is thrown by the moveconstructor of a
>   non-`CopyInsertable T`, the effects are unspecified.

Which de facto enforces the same behavior as the newer wording.

Now, speaking theoretically, if an implementation had additional means to detect whether a function can throw besides looking for the `noexcept` (e.g. through static analysis of the move constructor's implementation) would it be allowed to still move under the C++11 wording? The answer is yes, but I am not aware of any implementation that went through such considerable effort to enable a rather benign optimization like this.

Comment: "the decision of whether to move or copy will be based on std::move_if_noexcept" Where is this specified? There is no reference to `move_if_noexcept` in the whole "containers" chapter of the (draft) standard.

Comment: @geza Expanded the answer. Note that we are now really getting into hair splitting territory here. The only relevant part to your question really is the first paragraph. While an interesting mental exercise, none of the paragraphs that follow contain any useful practical information. Everything else is between you and your compiler vendor.

Comment: Your answer contains a contradiction: first you say "Even though it may not be obvious, this enforces calling the copy constructor when is_­nothrow_­move_­constructible_­v is false, as that is the only way for an implementation to comply with this requirement.", then "Now, speaking theoretically, ...". The first statement is wrong. The standard doesn't say at that part the copy must be used in this case. Because, as you say, a compiler may prove that move doesn't throw, even in the absence of `noexcept`...

Comment: ... So if it can prove that move doesn't throw, then the compiler can use it, and it will be standard conformant. The rule "if `-fnoexcept` then use move" doesn't seem to be a considerable effort either. So I consider this a missed optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Vector calls `move_if_noexcept`, which is designed to move if move copy constructor is defined as `noexcept`. Since you don't have `noexcept`, it's formally not `noexcept`, even if you never throw. Thus, it's not allowed to perform a move.

Considering you can mark all functions `noexcept` because you don't care about exceptions, I don't understand your concern.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your verbatim question:

The Standard mandates that there be exceptions. If you disallow your compiler to use exceptions, the compiler operates outside of the Standard and the Standard has nothing to say about the behavior of your program.

That said, the `move_if_noexcept` condition that `std::vector` inquires is not asking whether the move constructor is able to throw exceptions in the compiled program, but whether you declared the move constructor `noexcept`. Therefore, the observed behavior does not change whether or not you compile with `-fno-exceptions`.

---

Edit regarding your question in the comment:

> if move constructor is not noexcept, but the compiler can prove that the move constructor doesn't throw, is it allowed to use move constructor?

The compiler actually never comes to a point where it has the freedom to choose between the copy and the move constructor, not even if it could prove some suitable property by introspection.

So, the answer is no.

Somewhere in the code of `emplace_back` we will see something along the lines of

```
*dst = move_if_noexcept(*src);
```

Now, `move_if_noexcept` is specified as "use the move constructor if it is declared `noexcept`", but *not* specified as "use the move constructor if it does not throw an exception".

`emplace_back` *has* to be implemented in this generic way with `move_if_noexcept` to conform to the Standard for all possible value types. Of course, under `-fno-exceptions`, the compiler vendor could choose a different implementation, but as your experiments show, it doesn't.

Comment: Does the standard say that std::vector must use `move_if_noexcept`?

Comment: It is [specified implicitly](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/vector#modifiers-1) via the required behavior of `emplace_back`.

Comment: I don't really see why would that paragraph mean that. It just says, *If an exception is thrown*, ... . But, in my question, there is no exception thrown. The compiler knows it. Even, I could have asked: "if move constructor is not `noexcept`, but the compiler can prove that the move constructor doesn't throw, is it allowed to use move constructor?" Because it seems that it is allowed, based on that paragraph.

Comment: You say "the compiler knows it" because of `-fno-exceptions`? If so, then the Standard is the wrong document to consult, because it has nothing to say about your program. If you permit exceptions by dropping `-fno-exceptions`, then the compiler "knows it" only if you declare the move constructor `noexcept`.

Comment: @geza Exceptions can be thrown with `-fno-exceptions`.

Comment: If my struct is completely empty, then the compiler knows, that the move constructor doesn't throw, without specifying `noexcept`. It still uses copy (almost empty example: https://godbolt.org/z/z8dQTo). The question is, is the copy mandated by the standard? Because as I see, it doesn't. It just says, that std::vector guarantees strong exception safety. But it can still guarantee it, if I don't specify `noexcept` on move constructor, but it can be proven that move constructor doesn't throw.

Comment: @Ayxan: maybe (can you give a reference?). But that wouldn't make too much sense. What would happen with local objects with destructors? They must be properly destroyed. With `-fno-exceptions`, they won't. Between the place where an exception is thrown, and where it gets caught (I mean the call stack), all C++ code must be exception aware.

Comment: @geza try `new int[SIZE_MAX]`. It'll most likely throw `bad_alloc`.